# undefined reference to 'freeHeap'

Tags: c, function, reference, undefined

I have encountered a problem when calling my freeHeap function inside of sortComp.c

I am calling it as such

```
heapRef myHeap = buildHeap(numData, heapSort, numData);     

freeHeap(myHeap);
```

When compiling I recieve the error "Undefined reference to 'freeHeap'"

I am including heap.h and inside of heap.h i have declared freeHeap

```
void freeHeap(heapRef *);
```

I am compiling it as such

```
gcc -o sortComp sortComp.c insertionSort.c heap.c insertionSort.h heap.h
```

It is defined in heap.c as

```
void freeHeap(heapRef *pH){
   heapRef H = *pH;
   free(H->data);
   free(H);
}
```

FIXED:

I changed the calling of 
    freeHeap(myHeap);

to

```
freeHeap(&myHeap);
```

and it stopped complaining

Comment: It also has to be declared in heap.h

Comment: but all of my other functions are simply declared in heap.h then defined in heap.c
this is the only function that isnt working

Comment: How is it declared in heap.h?

Comment: void freeHeap(heapRef);

Comment: What type does `myHeap` have?

Comment: Going by your definition for `freeHeap()`,you are supposed to declare it as `void freeHeap(heapRef *)`

Comment: okay I changed it to void freeHeap(heapRef *); but it still is giving me the same error

Comment: Do you have a forward declaration for heapRef in heap.h? Like `class heapRef;`

Comment: yea I use typedef struct heap *heapRef;

Comment: Does compiling `heap.c` alone work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in the declaration of your function `freeHeap()` in `heap.h` :

```
  extern void freeHeap(heapRef*);
```

**Edit** Jesus Christ, your argument to `freeHeap()` doesn't match with the prototype's, just as your declaration doesn't match with your definition.So your argument needs to be of type `heapRef*` instead of `heapRef`.In your program `myHeap` is of type `heapRef` while you are supposed to pass `heapRef*`.Use this:

```
freeHeap(&myHeap);
```

Comment: But you have to use `extern` nevertheless when you have declaration in one file and definition in another.

Comment: and use `heapRef*` in the declaration, not `heapRef`

Comment: why would freeHeap() require being extern when my heap.h file has 6 other functions that dont have extern and can be called without any problem in another file

Comment: It's something with your command on the command line that you are missing.Since I use a GUI to compile stuff,I see no error.

Comment: and extern didnt fix my problem either

Comment: yea all of the other functions in heap.h can be called fine and work perfectly

Comment: @user2345160 Ok, the problem might have been solved,but I just don't understand why your compiler gives THAT error!!It should point out to the type mismatch of the argument to `freeHeap()` and it's `declaration`,but instead it says it `freeHeap()` itself is undefined.Don't you agree?

Comment: You said, 'You see, though you are including the header file heap.h in your program, and though this header file contains the declaration for freeHeap(),it has no "connection" with the definition in another file heap.c as long as you don't declare the function as extern.' But this seems to contradict that claim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367124/should-functions-be-made-extern-in-header-files

Comment: @roliu I would go by Jonathan Leffler's answer: `Functions declared in headers are normally (unless you work really hard) extern. Personally, I prefer to see the explicit keyword there - but the compiler doesn't need it. It reminds the readers that they are extern, and since humans are more fallible than computers, I find the reminder helps.` I too prefer the explicit keyword.But in the OP's question, the real source of the trouble was very simple--He was passing an argument of type `heapRef` instead of the expected `heapRef*`.But still, the nature of the error displayed is confusing.

Comment: @roliu Thanks for pointing it out though,I won't be `that` fussy about `extern` for `functions` anymore.But for variables,one has to!!

Comment: I agree that `extern` is nice for readability. But suggesting that the compiler can't figure out where that function is is false (at least according to those answers). All I was suggesting is that you remove that claim from your answer. Since you did, we're in good order :)

Comment: @roliu How did you immediately get the link to that question?Was that in your list of favorites?Please tell me so that I can make use of StackOverflow better.I mean this link -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367124/should-functions-be-made-extern-in-header-files

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I used [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=extern+functions+headers&aq=f&oq=extern+functions+headers&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.6345j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Or if you're afraid of the google overlords then the third link using [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=extern+functions+headers) also seems sufficient

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I think anyone serious about learning a language would just refer to the specs though. Like if you are using `gcc` you'd refer to the spec here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards. It says there that it supports various C standards (although with varying levels of completion) and you can refer to those C standards to know what your compiler will actually do. But that's a lot of work... and only worth it if you're serious about knowing your language of choice. SO is generally good about accuracy if an answer gets enough exposure.

Comment: @roliu I wouldn't like to go **that** deeply into it,even though I would like to.I have time constraints,and have to work on my Discrete Maths too.Not to mention I have to start `Analysis of Algorithms` from scratch.Let's hope StackExchange is of help in those subjects too.

Answer (score 0):

Please take the .h files out of your compile command. It should probably be:

```
gcc -o sortComp sortComp.c insertionSort.c heap.c
```

Comment: I only put them in there because it wasnt working without them. I tried it again without them though and it still is giving me the same error

Comment: Have you tried to compile each of the files into .o files first? i.e.
gcc -c sortComp.c;
gcc -c insertionSorce.c;
gcc -c heap.c;